# page event when using page methods?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following that I'm using in every page:

```
public partial class Pages_MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   ViewUserPreferencesModel TheUserPreferences;

   Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      TheUserPreferences = (ViewUserPreferencesModel)Session["SessionUserPreferences"];
```

And then I use a Page Method like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetAppointements(string DateInput)
{
   ViewUserPreferencesModel TheUserPreferences = (ViewUserPreferencesModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionUserPreferences"];
```

My question is this: Do I need to include the statement that loads user preferences when I run the page method or are the statements in the Page_Load event triggered when the page method is called, and if they are, will the variable be populated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Page Methods do not follow the ASP.NET page lifecycle. However, even if they did, your TheUserPreferences variable won't be accessible in the static context.

Comment: ok, thanks. I guess that means I'll have to keep it as is. Is there a better way that you can suggest?

Comment: @frenchie, depends what your page method does. Typically you use page methods to do some kind of async call to return data or to do an update. So it's not clear why your page method needs user preferences.

Comment: Because in the UserPreferences, I store the way the user wants to display times and dates. The page method returns a json object that gets formatted according to the user's preferences.

Comment: @frenchie, then sounds like you'll need to do it the way you have